# How can I spread a List in Dart

Tags: dart

I am ne to dart.
**In python it was**

```
[["A","B"],["C","D","E"],["F","G"]]
```

In dart It was Showing error Help me

Comment: coluld you please explain your question?   [Check spread operator in official docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are receiving the data, at runtime, in the mentioned form, you would not easily be able to use the spread operator, as the others have suggested.

Instead, you can use the [`expand`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) function and create a new list based on this result like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final list = [["A","B"],["C","D","E"],["F","G"]];
  final list2 = [...list.expand((e) => e)];
  
  print(list2); // [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use spread operator '...'

```
[...["A","B"],...["C","D","E"],...["F","G"]]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```dart
void main() {
  // example 1
  print([...['A', 'B'], ...['C', 'D', 'E'], ...['F', 'G']]);
  // output: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]

  // example 2
  var characters1 = <String>['A', 'B'];
  var characters2 = <String>['C', 'D', 'E'];
  var characters3 = <String>['F', 'G'];
  var allCharacters = [...characters1, ...characters2, ...characters3];
  print(allCharacters);
  // output: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
}
```

> Read [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) for more about the `spread operator ...`